# Can not install docker to centos 6.1

Tags: centos, software-installation, docker

```
[root@tomcat bin]# yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.vargonen.com
 * epel: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: centos.vargonen.com
 * rpmforge: mirrors.nav.ro
 * updates: centos.vargonen.com
docker-ce-stable                                                                                                                                                                                                      | 3.5 kB     00:00
docker-ce-stable/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                           |  28 kB     00:00
docker-ce-test                                                                                                                                                                                                        | 3.5 kB     00:00
docker-ce-test/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                             |  87 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.5-3.1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: containerd.io-1.2.5-3.1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: containerd.io-1.2.5-3.1.el7.x86_64
---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2.9 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libseccomp >= 2.3 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcgroup for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: xz for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
---> Package docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.5-3.1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: containerd.io-1.2.5-3.1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: containerd.io-1.2.5-3.1.el7.x86_64
---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2.9 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libseccomp >= 2.3 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64
---> Package libcgroup.x86_64 0:0.40.rc1-27.el6_10 will be installed
---> Package xz.x86_64 0:4.999.9-0.5.beta.20091007git.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: systemd-units
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.5-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.0-1.4.beta4.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: libseccomp >= 2.3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I get this error.

i follow this tutorial.

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/

I made

```
--skip-broken
```

but this time

```
[root@tomcat bin]# systemctl start docker
-bash: systemctl: command not found
[root@tomcat bin]# docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
[root@tomcat bin]# service docker start
docker: unrecognized service
```

i got those errors

Comment: You are trying to install software for CentOS 7 on CentOS 6. Same problem as in your other question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519027/can-not-install-mysql-to-centos

Comment: @Panki i could not find any guides for centos6

Comment: ... and why is that? Because it's not supported!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker-ce` isn't supported on centos 6.

> [OS requirements](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#os-requirements)
>
> To install Docker CE, you need a maintained version of CentOS 7. Archived versions aren’t supported or tested.